# How to run/call CtrlP first time in the background - VIM

Tags: vim, ctrlp

When calling **CtrlP** for the first time it cause quite a delay to build the cache. Is there a way to run it in the background so I can continue doing stuff in vim?

Comment: No, Vim doesn't do asynchronous execution. Start Vim from the root of your project, not from your `$HOME`.

Comment: @romainl That might need to be updated for Vim 8.

Comment: @romainl, is there a way to build the cache continuously? it seems if I havent build the cache in a while, ctrlp will try to build the cache the first time I boot up ctrlp, and it ends up taking a while.. I am using vim8 which has async feature..

Comment: @alpha_989, I've stopped using that plugin a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, in fact, [vim isn't multi-threaded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179335/84052).

You can look over for [NeoVim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) which is multi-threaded.

Alternativly, you could use the [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) plugin and the `file_rec/async` command :

> Note: with large projects this may cause some performance problems.
>   Normally it is recommended to use |unite-source-file_rec/async|
>   source, which requires |vimproc|.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have installed NeoVim. How can I do it with NeoVim? When I run CtrlP it stucks till it finishes the indexation like in Vim.

Comment: CtrlP has been abandoned for a few years, now, and thus doesn't benefit from the new features in neovim.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to speed up indexing of **CtrlP**, you can use [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to grep files, exclude some folders and files from indexing, and set cache location.

To do that, put these lines in your .vimrc:

```
let g:ctrlp_cache_dir = $HOME . '/.cache/ctrlp'
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -i --nocolor --nogroup --hidden
  \ --ignore .git
  \ --ignore .svn
  \ --ignore .hg
  \ --ignore .DS_Store
  \ --ignore "**/*.pyc"
  \ -g ""'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work much faster with ag.

Comment: Does ctrlp use grep by default? ie. when nothing is mentioned?