# Vim Ctrl+P file search is Ignoring Directories With Dashes

Tags: vim, vi, ctrlp

I am using the vim Ctrl+P plugin for file searching,

All that is listed in my `.vimrc` is

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\.git$\|CVS$\|build|\.svn$\|target$',
  \ 'file': '\.class$\|\.so$',
  \ }
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['dir', 'mixed']
```

But it does not seem to index any directories that have a `-` in them. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `build|\.svn$\|`. You need to escape that pipe character.

Comment: @TankorSmash That definitely helped speed up one of my projects.. but unfortunately does not fix my problem.

Comment: I know it is probably unnecessary but did you check `set wildignore?` if there is nothing set of that sort? If you need to speed up your CtrlP (I answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516838/how-to-run-call-ctrlp-first-time-in-the-background-vim/32520039#32520039)), you should use [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

Comment: Also are you using [the active fork of CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)? The original one is [unmaintained](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/669). If nothing helps, you should probably visit [its issue tracker](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/issues).

Comment: Woah, thank you so much @ryuichiro - The problem was that I was using the old unmaintained `kien/ctrlp.vim` rather than the active fork, `ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim`. If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **CtrlP**, be careful which version you use. There is no longer maintained [`kien/ctrlp.vim`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim), and its active fork [`ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim`](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim).

Also, if you need to speed up your **CtrlP**, you should consider to use [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher). The integration with Vim can provide [`ag.vim`](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) plugin. About ignore setting you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516838/how-to-run-call-ctrlp-first-time-in-the-background-vim/32520039#32520039).